# Hiding combobox items based on choice of second combobox, vice versa

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, visibility

I have two comboboxes, each are bound(!) to the same `ObservableCollection<string>`. I want to prevent the selection of the same Items.

Here is my C# code (the firstload bool is just to prevent the execution the first time the function is loaded):

```
private void comboBoxFilter1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!firstload)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= comboBoxFilter2.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((((ComboBoxItem)(comboBoxFilter2.Items[i])).Content as string) == (((ComboBoxItem)comboBoxFilter1.SelectedItem).Content as string))
            // This is where I get the InvalidCaseException ^
            {
                (comboBoxFilter2.Items[i] as ComboBoxItem).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                //and on this line the nullreferenceException, in particular, although the Item[i] does have Value!
            }
            else
            {
                (comboBoxFilter2.Items[i] as ComboBoxItem).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                //and on this line the nullreferenceException, in particular, although the Item[i] does have Value!
            }
        }
    }
}

private void comboBoxFilter2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    if (!firstload)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= comboBoxFilter1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((((ComboBoxItem)(comboBoxFilter1.Items[i])).Content as string) == (((ComboBoxItem)comboBoxFilter2.SelectedItem).Content as string))
            {
                (comboBoxFilter1.Items[i] as ComboBoxItem).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show((comboBoxFilter2.Items[i] as ComboBoxItem).Visibility.ToString());
                (comboBoxFilter1.Items[i] as ComboBoxItem).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }

    firstload = false;
}
```

Here is my Xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxFilter1" 
          Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.Row="2"     
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"     
          SelectionChanged="comboBoxFilter1_SelectionChanged" 
          SelectedIndex="0"     
          Visibility="Visible"/>    

<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxFilter2" 
          Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"     
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"     
          SelectionChanged="comboBoxFilter2_SelectionChanged" 
          SelectedIndex="1"    
          Visibility="Visible"/>
```

Note, that I do the Itemsource in Code, not in Xaml.

When running, I get a `NullReferenceExecption` or an `InvalidCastException` (see comments in code). The same errors happen in the `comboBoxFilter2_SelectionChange` method.

Comment: pls excuse my horrible post-making, I dont really understand how the formatting works..

Comment: The Nullreference Exceptions can occur, when the safe cast `(Combobox.Items[i] as ComboboxItem)` does not succeed. You should debug and have a look at the exact type of the values.

Comment: I would suggest using an `IMultiValueConverter` and binding the `Visibility` of the first `ComboBox` to the `SelectedItem` of the first and second `ComboBox` using the converter and the other way round. Much cleaner and easier to understand and without code behind.

Comment: Buy the way: do you really want to collapse both `ComboBox` when the same item is selected?

Comment: id like to have the first Combobox displaying [a,b,c,e] where a is selected, and the second Combobox displaying [b,c,d,e] where d is selected

Comment: the Problem seems to only occur because im binding a collection. When im just adding the Content via Items.Add, this method works just fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such tasks are really easy with MVVM, where you rarely have to use view events/elements to achieve needed.

If you have xaml like this one:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected1}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List2}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected2}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then all the logic can go into viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "") => 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

    readonly List<string> _list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    public IEnumerable<string> List1 => _list.Where(o => o != Selected2);
    public IEnumerable<string> List2 => _list.Where(o => o != Selected1);

    string _selected1;
    public string Selected1
    {
        get { return _selected1; }
        set
        {
            _selected1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(List2));
        }
    }

    string _selected2;
    public string Selected2
    {
        get { return _selected2; }
        set
        {
            _selected2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(List1));
        }
    }
}
```

Note: when view changes selected items, then the viewmodel simply triggers `NotifyPropertyChanged` event for properties used in bindings and their values are evaluated.

Usage:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel() { Selected1 = "a", Selected2 = "d" };
    }
}
```

[image]